# Save automatic android espresso Tests Results

Tags: automated-tests, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

How we would save our Test results in object after that test finished in success/failure status. I need the result data like date/time of started test, time elapsed and etc.

[image]

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can export your tests results using "*Export Test Results*" option to *.html*, or *.xml* file.

[image: Export Test Results img]

If that's not enough, then look at the android test output console. You can copy-paste the commands and create your own script using e.g. powershell, or anything you want. Also check [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html)

[image: Export Test Results Script img]

**edit:**
Ahh, sorry I think I didn't read properly. You want to catch the result as a object in code after every test? So.. you can't use `@after` - your function can't takes any parameters. By using [TestWatcher](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) you can get `Description` object, but I don't saw the informations about test time. But if you calculate time in your own..

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestClass {

    private long startTime;

    @Rule
    public TestRule watcher = new TestWatcher() {

        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }
    };

    @org.junit.Test
    public void Test() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //your test here
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!